# Angular UI router throwing error when using multiple resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `AngularJS v1.6.10` and `angular-ui-router v1.0.18`, which throws the error:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dashboardDataProvider <- dashboardData <- dashBoardCtrl

but when I am using `AngularJS v1.6.10` and `angular-ui-router v0.4.2` it's working fine.

#### Sample Code

```
$stateProvider.state('root.dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    resolve:loadSequence('dashBoardCtrl'),  
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: BaseURL + '/templates/dashboard/index.html',
            controller: 'dashBoardCtrl',
            resolve: {
                dashboardData:function(dbService){
                    return dbService.getDashboardData();
                }
            },
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: resolve should be per state, not per nested view

Comment: but is working in angular-ui-router v0.4.2

Comment: What is the function loadSequence from here `resolve:loadSequence('dashBoardCtrl')`?

Comment: loadSequence : load given file in head tag

Comment: Maybe something to do with [this breaking change](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-change-move-imperative-resolve-service-out-of-main-bundle)?

Comment: Could you include whats inside of `loadSequence('dashBoardCtrl')`

Comment: Please include `dashBoardCtrl` controller code, I think you need to inject `dashboardData` in controller

Answer (score 0):

Aleksey Solovey is quite correct. A breaking change between ui-router v0.x and v1.x is the removal of support for resolve within nested views. So you need to move the call to `dbService` out:

```
$stateProvider.state('root.dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  resolve: {
      dashboardData:function(dbService) {
        return dbService.getDashboardData();
      },
      // Probably wrong, because I don't understand your intention here
      other: loadSequence('dashBoardCtrl')
  },
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: BaseURL + '/templates/dashboard/index.html',
      controller: 'dashBoardCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

This difference is clearly described in the [UI-Router 1.0 Migration](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#breaking-changes) document. However, I found this SO entry first, so stuck in this answer to help others with poor Google-foo.